# How to push 0 item to the stack of int?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a simple stack implementation. But I cant realize how programmer solve the following problem: It is not possible to push a 0 to the stack. How to do that? I mean how to track is it a `0` value or just end of the stack? Or its not a problem in my implementation?

```
public class Stack: IStack
{
    private int[] s;
    private int N = 0;

    public Stack(int N)
    {
        s = new int[N];
    }

    public void push(int x)
    {
        s[N++] = x;

        if (N >= s.Length)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref s, s.Length*2);
        }
    }

    public int pop()
    {
        s[N] = 0;
        return s[--N];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it not possible to push a 0 to the stack?  What prevents that?

Comment: `if (x==0) throw new InvalidArgumentException()`?

Comment: The `N` member is used to track the top of the stack so you need to check that. It looks like it should be initialised to -1 to indicate the stack is empty.

Comment: @ivan what makes you think so?

Comment: It is not needed, but if you want an indication in the array itself that a value is not used, then you need to use a value that would never be used. Instead of `0` you could use something like [Int32.MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or have an array of `int?` and set the value to `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already tracking the last element of the stack with `N` (or rather, `N - 1`). You don't need to verify whether the element is `0`, and your implementation actually doesn't distinguish between zeroes and other numbers.

In the implementation you provided, it is perfectly possible to push a `0` into the stack.

By the way, I would reimplement your `pop()` method like this:

```
public int? pop()
{
    if (N != 0)
    {
        return s[--N];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This way, it returns `null` in case the stack is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You should realize that it doesn't matter what the values `S[N], S[N+1], ...` are since you are only using the values `S[0..N-1]` for your implementation. You consider the part `S[N...]` as uninitialized and adding a new element, even `0`, causes `S[N]` to become initialized as the new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can push 0 nothing prevents it. `N` is equal to number of elements, it's also used to track index of next item to push `N == (index of last element + 1)`. The problem i see is that if you run pop() too many times you will get `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

You can add IsEmpty property like this:

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    get { return N < 1; }
}
```